# change of possession at halftime

Tags: rules, basketball

Is the following correct?  In a high school basketball game, the first half ends with the possession arrow favoring black.  Therefore, to start the second half, black throws the ball in.  Once the throw in is completed, the possession arrow changes to white. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is correct. Once the ball is in-bounded the possession arrow switches.

See [this website](http://www.livestrong.com/article/351273-basketball-rules-on-changing-the-possession-arrow/) for more info about possession arrows if you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

According to the 2014-2015 NFHS Basketball Rulebook (the latest I can find that was accessible - **not accessible without purchase**), this is known as "alternating-possession" as found in Rule 6, Section 4.

Article 1 states:

> Other than the start of the game and each extra period, the teams will alternate taking the ball out of bounds for a throw-in.

Article 4 states:

> The direction of the possession arrow is reversed immediately after an
>   alternating possession throw-in ends

In your scenario, the possession arrow does change.

Comment: at half time the teams change direction. So scorers are instructed not to touch the arrow at half time?  So the refs know it is facing the wrong way for the inbound to start the second half?

Comment: @philsoady I don't have a NFHS rulebook to refer to, but the NCAA rulebook states in Rule 6, Section 3, Article 6: "Before the start of the second half, the direction of the possession arrow
shall be changed to account for the teams switching ends of the court." I assume the NFHS rulebook has similar verbiage.

Comment: That is what i expecting.  Thanks Mastermind